# Java Scanner, Arraylist and while loop

Tags: java

I am trying a to get user input and add the value in Arraylist as long it is positive number. If user enters a negative number the program should stop. This is my code it take up to three numbers then stops.
Thank you in advance.

```
class ProjectOne{

public void counterLoop() {
    Scanner userNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList();

    System.out.println("Enter Your No: ");
    number.add(userNumber.nextInt());

    while (true){
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        number.add(userNumber.nextInt());
        System.out.println(number);

        if (userNumber.nextInt() >= 0){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ok? and what is your actual question? You have a codebase to start from, you know what must change. What is stopping you? try in your if, to change userNumber.nextInt() to number, since you already read the number

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I have tried number inside if statement but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void counterLoop() {
    Scanner userNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int n = userNumber.nextInt();
        if(n >= 0)
            number.add(n);
        else break;
    }
}
```

You should add the number to the list iff it is >= 0. If a negative number is input, the loop should break. You can print your list to see the result,

```
for(int i : number)
   System.out.print(i + " ");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a dream :)